# Reference for: Probability Measures are Closed under Convex Combination

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

I would like to reference this fact (probability measures are closed under convex combination).
I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) (*for example, probability distributions are closed under convex combination*) but I would rather want to cite a paper/textbook.
I would be happy if someone could provide such a reference (ideally to a paper or a book for which a PDF is freely available).

Comment: Prove it yourself!  It is a one-liner.

Comment: Hm, I found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20230329122526/https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linear_Combination_of_Measures) (although I did not really had a look) and I have no doubt about the validity of the property. But, clearly, it is not adequate to include/publish (what most people would consider) trivial already existing proofs in my papers. Instead, I just need a valid reference... I do not even need a proof; I only need a rather trustworthy source that makes that claim.

Comment: you don't need a reference because 1) it's well-known 2)it's so trivial that even if the reader did not know, they could see it instantly